# javascript style on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a game menu on javascript, I'm generating HTML with javascript because of practice.

I got this event listener that I should click to obtain the lhyperlink to another page, but when it appears, the hyperlink instead of getting centered by CSS stylesheet, it goes default and gets to the left.

I don't know how it's called in CSS

Here's my code:

```
const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
const parr1 = document.createElement("p");
const parr2 = document.createElement("p");
body.appendChild(h1);
body.appendChild(parr1);
body.appendChild(parr2);
h1.innerHTML = "Aventura D&D";
parr1.innerHTML = "Empezar Juego";
parr2.innerHTML = "Cargar juego";

parr1.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    let link = document.createTextNode('Juego Nuevo');
    a.appendChild(link);
    a.title = "Juego Nuevo";
    a.href = '/game1.html';
    //Here is the problem!!!!
    document.body.replaceChild(a, parr1);
});
```

I went to the Element Inspector and I was able to modify the element by modifying the `body` tag. Why?

Here is the CSS sheet

```
body{

    background: black;
    color: goldenrod;
    //This is the part that is working but I wonder why if the spawned                                                                                                                                  //hyperlink should obey <a> tag
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    font-size: 9em;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    color: #c90000;
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you should always prefer `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` because it's faster and more importantly: it's safer (due to the risk of XSS and other script-injection attacks)

Comment: ```a.style.textAlign``` also doesn't work?

Comment: `a.styles` is not a property, maybe try `a.style.alignText = "center";`,  also you can use `document.body.append(el, el2, el3)` for multiple elements instead. The issue with `document.body.replaceChild(a, parr1)` is, that it's never appended to the body, so how would you replace it?

Comment: @IlkyunIm no, it doesn't work, sadly

Comment: The problem might be your style sheet. Is it possible to add it?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would change from where it says `document.body.replaceChild(a, parr1);` to say `document.body.replaceChild(a, this);`. There may be an issue with referencing.
2. For the text alight, try using `a.style.textAlign = "center";` rather than `a.styles.cssText('align-text: "center;')`

Comment: using `this` doesn't work, and neither `style.textAlign` it goes to not work at all.